# 'long' object has no attribute 'id' error in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am working on django and stuck in a problem. This is the code snippet for *views.py*:

```
    tz = pytz.timezone('Asia/Kolkata')
    product_sync_ts= datetime.now(tz)
    product_sync_ts = "2016-03-10 14:41:48.901013+05:30"
    product = Product.objects.filter(update_ts__lt=product_sync_ts , enabled_flag = True , ).values_list('id', flat=True)
    product_upcs = ProductUPC.objects.filter(update_ts__lt = product_sync_ts , enabled_flag=True).values_list('product' , flat=True)

    print product
    print product_upcs
```

I am trying to get all the ids of product from the table product whose timestamp is greater than **product_sync_ts**. Same thing I am doing for table ProductUPC table also.

**productUPC model**

```
class ProductUPC(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey('Product', related_name='upcs')
    upc = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True, null=False)
    install_ts = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    update_ts = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    enabled_flag = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

**Product model**

```
 class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    price = models.IntegerField()
    enabled_flag = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    install_ts = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    update_ts = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

The error that I am getting is:

```
'long' object has no attribute 'id'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/
Django Version: 1.8
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'long' object has no attribute 'id'
```

Traceback:

```
/Users/folder/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in get_response
                    response = middleware_method(request, callback, callback_args, callback_kwargs)
                    if response:
                        break
            if response is None:
                wrapped_callback = self.make_view_atomic(callback)
                try:
                                response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) ...
                except Exception as e:
                    # If the view raised an exception, run it through exception
                    # middleware, and if the exception middleware returns a
                    # response, use that. Otherwise, reraise the exception.
                    for middleware_method in self._exception_middleware:
                        response = middleware_method(request, e)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do `update_ts__gt=product_sync_ts`, because `product_sync_ts` is a string, but the field `update_ts` is a `DateTimeField`. You need to convert the variable `product_sync_ts` to DateTimeField first then do the query.

Comment: I don't understand your question. You can convert individual `update_ts` value to string, but you cannot use string format to do django ORM query.

Comment: yeah I got that...sorry for such a silly question ;)

Comment: Do you have full stack trace of your exception?

Comment: That's not the full traceback, it doesn't say where the exception occurs.

Comment: I have changed the code..please see if you can figure out now...still getting the same problem